# What are the providers and aliases needed for dompdf/dompdf 0.8.1 in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have installed dompdf/dompdf with version 0.8.1 package for my laravel 5.3.My question is what providers and aliases classes do i have to give in my config/app.php file.
I have given
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
    and
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,

But it showed error:
Class 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider' not found.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a different one. Your providers and aliases are fine. You need to run following code.

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"`

By running this command default configuration sets up.

You can find it on instruction of Barrvdh package installation [[link]](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#configuration)

Comment: i installed dompdf/dompdf not the Barryvdh\DomPDF so will my providers and aliases will be different

Comment: Installing composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf again solved the issue.Thanks.